# SQL Select to identify device status based on the multiple status fields values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions, coalesce

Need to get the status of each id based on the priority of columns by filling the details of null values with the old record values.

I have a table called notifications which have a fields like error, warning, running and stopped and so on other statuses.

These status's fills the data in SQL as shown below

```
+---+-------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | utctimestamp            |Trip   |Warning| start |  Load|
+---+-------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 0 | 2018-12-03 06:56:51.955 |       |       | true  | true  |
| 1 | 2018-12-03 03:41:31.664 |       |       |       |       |
| 0 | 2018-12-03 03:26:29.099 |       | false |       |       |
| 1 | 2018-12-02 20:33:07.0   |       |       | false | false |
| 1 | 2018-12-02 20:23:21.092 |       | true  | false | false |
| 0 | 2018-12-02 18:06:45.003 | true  |       |       |       |
| 0 | 2018-12-02 13:51:03.575 |       | false | false | false |
| 1 | 2018-12-02 13:50:24.614 | false | false | false | false |
| 0 | 2018-12-02 07:24:00.996 |       |       | true  | true  |
| 1 | 2018-12-02 04:08:41.36  | false |       |       |       |
| 0 | 2018-12-02 03:53:40.193 |       | false |       |       |
| 0 | 2018-12-01 18:32:24.271 | false |       |       |       |
```

status will be calculated with the priority given to trip > warning> start > load, and the values has to be filled with the old record value if it is null.

From the above table details we need to derive the status of id's 0 and 1 based on their status's.

For the 0, even start status is true we need to consider the status of it as trip because the last trip occurred record is still in true status only.

Like the same way for Id 1 the previous old record contains the warning as true (and previous records which contain the trip status as false), so the status of 1 is warning.

The desired output is

```
+---+-------------------------+
| id | status                 |
+---+-------------------------+
| 0 | trip                    |
| 1 | warning                 |
```

for this i am struggling to find or frame the query in SQL. any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hi Gordan, I am using amazon redshift and even i tried this example in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You want `lag()` with ignore nulls:

```
select s.*,
       coalesce(trip, lag(trip ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by utctimestamp)) as imputed_trip,
       coalesce(Warning, lag(Warning ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by utctimestamp)) as imputed_Warning,
       coalesce(start, lag(start ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by utctimestamp)) as imputed_start,
       coalesce(Load, lag(Load ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by utctimestamp)) as imputed_Load
from statuses s;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordan, With the above SQL query i can able to fill the null values with the previous existing value. But how to find the final status of the id's based on the priority of the columns(trip > warning > start > load) by considering the above query.